# Mysql Where and between query to database

Tags: mysql, sql, select

`SELECT name, address FROM global WHERE (type=3) AND WHERE (id BETWEEN 3 and 7);`
syntax issue. but the idea is to only get row between 3 and 7 from the type 3 column.

I remove one of the () so WHERE(type=3) AND WHERE id BETWEEN 3 and 7. same error

Comment: Use the handy github link for Mysql related syntax issues: https://gist.github.com/hofmannsven/9164408

Comment: Thanks, this is gold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a between operator as below:

```
SELECT name, address FROM global WHERE type=3 
AND id BETWEEN 3 and 7;
```

Comment: i.e. remove the second `WHERE`. The parenthesis are entirely optional.

Comment: Thanks, second where was not necessary. Now i got it